# react-big-calendar bug when clicking on show more events

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-big-calendar

[image]

I'm using react-big-calendar (in my next.js project) and as you can see in the image above I'm displaying events on it and I have a bug that I can't understand why its happening.

When I press on the `+3 more` (which shows me all the events happening on the given day) then the dropdown menu that you can see on the top right image opens and then instantly closes and even if I change page it still gives me the same bug and it happens to all the dropdowns that I have on the website I'm working on.

Now one "hack" is to make the `min height` of the calendar bigger (I can make it 900px instead of the current 700px) so that all 4 events are shown directly instead of showing the `+3 more` but the problem with this "hack" is that imagine I have A LOT of events on a given day then I would need to set the `min height` to really really big number which is undesirable.

Note that the bug disappear if I reload the page but obviously I just can't force the user to reload every time he wants to see more events on a given day.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of React-Big-Calendar are you using? Older versions of RBC used an anchor tag, for the 'more', that had an `href="#"`. I could see that causing issues like this. Current version has replaced this code with a 'button' component styled to look like an anchor.

Comment: no i'm using a recent version, i ended up making a modal that shows all the events instead of relying on the default behaviour.